# Как приостановить все потоки кроме одного

Tags: java, многопоточность, concurrency

Здравствуйте! Немножко абстрактный вопрос, потому без «настоящего» кода.

Представим, что у нас в программе есть n потоков (скажем 10). И некоторый k-ый поток (скажем 6-ой) выполняет что-то в духе:

```
t=getElapsedTime(); //  (1)
// (2)
position += speed*t; // (3)
```

В строке 1 мы записываем в локальную переменную `t` некоторого метода число, отображающее сколько времени в секундах прошло с предыдущего изменения позиции игрока.
Строка 2 (между 1 и 3) и вызывает у меня **вопрос**: можно ли избежать гипотетической передачи процессорного времени другим потокам, коих аж (n-1) штука (скажем аж 9) БЕЗ захвата всеми n потоками некоторой глобальной блокировки (что вообще извращение). Хочется чего-то из серии `Scheduler.giveAllTimeFor(Thread.currentThread())` перед первой строкой, а после третьей что-нибудь как `Scheduler.normal()`
Строка 3 собственно и является местом, где очень желательно пользовться значением `t` сразу, как оно инициализировалось.

**UPD:**
Не верно предлагать всякие `Barrier`s и `Latch`es, это из серии блокировок. Вопрос предельно прост: как заставить планировщик потоков Java перестать ставить на процессор потоки, кроме того, который об этом просит, до тех пор пока он же не попросит об обратном?

Очень странно, что «из коробки» этого метода не наблюдается, ведь для планировщика это расплюнуть.

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Чем то напоминает остановку всей JVM при сборке мусора. Можете попробовать обойти все потоки и вызвать методы suspend и resume у Thread. А ещё можно копнуть в сторону GC, там есть такая штука как stop-the-world, возможно там можно что-то узнать из исходников.

Comment: Thread'ы java соответствуют thread'ам операционной системы, соотв. надо сперва уговорить ос ничего не выполнять на ядре, а потом привязать к этому ядру свою нить чем-то типа [этой библиотеки](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Thread-Affinity).

Comment: `... без захвата всеми n потоками некоторой глобальной блокировки (что вообще извращение)...` то что Вы предлагаете (односторонне глушить все потоки) поизвращеннее будет

Comment: Односторонне? Глушить что-либо можно двусторонне?... Объясните, пожалуйста, что Вы хотели сказать. При чём тут «глушить»? Я хочу попросить планировщик не давать им время.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте остановить потоки в событии

```
 private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
 {
   Stream1.Close();
   Stream2.Close();
    /* итд
 }
```

Один из них не закрывайте и все.
На  данный момент конкретно в Java и С# нет такой функции какая бы выполняла ваше условие вопроса!

> Почитайте https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/8.2.php

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать использовать класс [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html), если заранее известно точное количество потоков.

Comment: Ну то, что приходит в голову, а именно: сделать .await() во всех потоках и дать нашему k-ому потоку MAX_PRIORITY, чтобы он при переходе барьера был поставлен на процессор — никак не поможет. Честно, даже не понимаю как тут замешать CyclicBarrier... можно как-то перед куском с нашими просчётами ждать (n-1) остальной поток, а в них ждать конца нашего куска, но понимаете, всё это речь о блокировках так или иначе. Нужно просто попросить планировщик временно не ставить никакой поток кроме k-ого...

Comment: Как-то сложно вы расписали: можно просто каждый из 9 потоков поставить вначале на await(), а в 10 вызвать await() после исполнения необходимых строк кода. Тогда после исполнения этого куска кода барьер упадет и все 10 потоков продолжат свою работу. Но если вы не хотите использовать блокировки, то может быть Вам подумать, как запустить потоки последовательно? Попробуйте нарисовать граф, какой поток от какого зависит, быть может, так будет проще.

Comment: Представим, что вот-вот они все перешли этот барьер. Процессор мог отдаться сразу k-ому потоку, он считывает время t, а затем время могло успешно уйти на все остальные потоки :) где профит?